# How to add onclick event into listview using a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a problem when try to add `setOnItemClickListener` into a Fragment.

This is my Fragment.

```
public class LocalesFragmento extends Fragment {

ListView locales_list;
private List localesList;

private Context context;

public LocalesFragmento() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locales_list, container, false);
    locales_list = (ListView) vista.findViewById(R.id.localesList);

    new getLocalesAsyncTask().execute();
    return vista;
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    Log.e("Adapter","Adapter...");
    locales_list.setAdapter(new LocalesAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), localesList));

    locales_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            //detailInstagram(list.get(position));
        }
    });
}
```

The setOnItemClickListener is never executed. Any ideas? 
Do I need to implement some other method?

Thanks.
Best regards.

Comment: Looks like you're not calling `setListAdapter` method. If you are, where are you calling that method from?

Comment: Yes I called this method... Before Execute the `AsyncTask` to get data form WebService.

Comment: What does your list item layout look like? If any view is clickable or focusable (e.g. it contains a Button), the listener will never be called.

Comment: The constructor for your LocalesAdapter seems strange to me.  I usually use getApplicationContext() assigned to a Context type variable mCtx in the instantiate call. You have getActivity() twice.  Why do you need a context twice?

Comment: post ur listview items layout. If u used any views which are having focus( Like Button,imageButton) then setOnItemClickListener won't call.

Comment: this is the ListView Layout.. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ListView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/localesList"
       android:focusable="false">

       </ListView>

</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

You start your AsyncTask on `onActivityCreated` method because here before attaching the layout you are starting an async and that may be the reason why the listener is setting up.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       locales_list.setAdapter(new LocalesAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), localesList));
       locales_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
              //detailInstagram(list.get(position));

            }
        });
        new getLocalesAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

Comment: If you are loading custom layout to listview, then add  android:focusable="false" to its childrens

Answer (score 0):

Your LocalesAdapter might be the cause. You are passing the context (getActivity()) to the adapter twice.

```
locales_list.setAdapter(new LocalesAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), localesList));
```

Make your that the arguments passed to the LocalesAdapter are correct.